# WSO2 ESB Dynamic Load-balance Endpoint balancing algorithm

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

i'm using WSO2 470 ESB.
I need to use a Dynamic Load Balancing endpoint providing my custom load-balancing policy.
I know that WSO2 is based on apache Synapse, on which i can find this:

http://synapse.apache.org/userguide/config.html#DLBEndpointConfig

Here is descbribed a Dynamic Load Balancer which i can set my custom algorithm for Membership handler.
On this page i can find the corresponding wso2 dynamic load balanced endpoint:

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Dynamic+Load-balance+Endpoint

In this page i read:

```
Currently only the roundRobin policy is supported.
```

Is it true? is there the possibility to customize balancing policy by my own class?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom implementation of org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.LoadbalanceAlgorithm. A JAR of this can be added to /repository/components/lib. This can then be added under ESB ->Endpoints -> Alogoritm ->Other, where the full class name of the implementation can be added. 
See [Writing a load balance algorithm for WSO2 ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169600/writing-a-load-balance-algorithm-for-wso2-esb) for a related question.